# Changing terminal color

Tags: macos, bash

I would like to know how to change the terminal color, so whenever I run 
`ls` it will return the name of:

- Directories in red
- Files in blue
- Executable files (those you do `./file`) in light green

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this is done with

```
ls -G
```

Personally I'm using an alias, e.g. in `.bash_aliases` which is loaded by `.bash_profile`

```
alias ls="ls -G"
```

However, there's another option, i.e. turning on `CLICOLOR` in your shell, e.g. by adding the following to your `.bash_profile`

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

Comment: I would use the "export CLICOLOR=1" version because this may also affect other commands whereas the "alias ls="ls -G" solution will "only" affect ls

Answer (score 4):

See this article ["ls, colors, and Terminal.app"](http://www.norbauer.com/rails-consulting/notes/ls-colors-and-terminal-app.html) to customize the default `ls` colors.

Basically, what you need to do is change the value of the `LSCOLORS` variable (default is `Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad` on OS X). Each letter represent a color:

- a = black
- b = red
- c = green
- d = brown
- e = blue
- f = magenta
- g = cyan
- h = grey
- A = dark grey
- B = bold red
- C = bold green
- D = yellow
- E = bold blue
- F = magenta
- G = cyan
- H = white
- x = default

And each two-letter group the foreground and background color for a type of entry.
For example, the first two letters make your directories being shown as Cyan (`G`) on a default (`x`) background (ie. the background color of your term).

The positions are:

1. directory
2. symbolic link
3. socket
4. pipe
5. executable
6. block device
7. character device
8. executable with setuid set
9. executable with setguid set
10. directory writable by others, with sticky bit
11. directory writable by others, without sticky bit

So to get the output you asked in your question, setting `LSCOLORS` to `bxfxcxdxcxegedabagacad` should do the trick, except for the "normal files" colors, which it seems can't be changed this way.

*All credits to Jonathan Dance for [the blog post linked earlier](http://www.norbauer.com/rails-consulting/notes/ls-colors-and-terminal-app.html), most of this answer is copied from it.*