# Changing terminal colors for normal files when ls -G or within .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, color

So I followed this thread ([Changing terminal color](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100297/changing-terminal-color)) and got all of the colors working for directories and such, except however, for normal files such as a Gemfile or .txt files or .java files or .rb files etc... I was wondering how I can get normal files to show up in color, even better if I can get different extensions of the file to show up in different colors as well. Let me know if you guys have any resources for this.

Comment: [This is a nice guide](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/05/improve-terminal-appearance-mac-os-x/), though I'm not sure as to whether it changes file as well as directory color (screenshot only shows top level traverse).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think colorizing the file names of regular files is possible with `ls` alone (*i.e.* without postprocessing the output with another script):

1. The manual page for `ls` (shown when you type `man ls`) does not mention this possibility.
2. I would expect that the `ls` coming with Mac OS X is very similar to the BSD version of `ls`, since there seems to be little motivation for Apple to make changes in this area.  The source code for BSD's `ls` is available online, *e.g.* the FreeBSD version is [on GitHub](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd).  The function which selects the color for a file name is `colortype()` in the source file `bin/ls/print.c`.  And checking [the source code](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/bin/ls/print.c#L474) it is clear that at least the BSD version of `ls` does not have the ability to change color when printing the names of a regular file.